# Firefox is not launched using Geckodriver and Selenium - It works with Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I've started using the Geckodriver today with no success.

The same scripts work using chrome (chrome launches correctly) but the Firefox browser is not being launched and TestNG fails the scripts before launching the browser.

The code is as simple as this:

```
       case "IE":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ECC.IE_DRIVER_PATH);
            localWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            break;
       case "FIREFOX":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ECC.FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH);
            localWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case "CHROME":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ECC.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
            localWebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            break;
        }
```

When performing the `localWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();`, it does not launches the browser, and it automatically goes to the `invoker.class` to the following code:

```
 catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
   testResult.setThrowable(ite.getCause());
   setTestStatus(testResult, ITestResult.FAILURE);
 }
```

The console only shows this:

> 1491601901866  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:27826

I'm using:

- FF version 48
- Geckodriver 15.0
- Selenium 3.3.1

I've also tried with the most updated version of FF without success.

This does not happens with chrome.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi! What is the specific error that gets thrown?

Comment: Before digging in further, have you tried the `DesiredCapabilities` way? `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
` You still have to set the `webdriver.gecko.driver` property using this method

Comment: Upgrade your Firefox to 52.0.1

Comment: I believe that upgrading FF should help you. As said in [Geckodriver Github page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver): "Support is best in Firefox 48 and onwards, although generally the more recent the Firefox version, the better the experience as...". Also, in [Selenium release for version 3.3.1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.3.1) there is a fix for "Fix an issue where setting the binary causes Firefox to be unable to start".

Comment: Hi all, I've tried those options and also with the latest FF version, without success. Regarding the error, I don't see any, basically TestNG fails the script like it ran normally, and the failure exception is caught when the code executes the:

         new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Found the solution. I had a problem with the Maven dependencies; by deleting the below one, the problem was solved.


<!--   <dependency> -->
<!--    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> -->
<!--    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId> -->
<!--    <version>2.51.0</version> -->
<!--   </dependency> -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to thank you for your responses. My problem was that I had a maven dependency which was causing problems I believe with the versions of what I was using. The dependency was:

```
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.51.0</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
```

By commenting these 2, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the latest version of Firefox. You would need to use 32-bit or 64-bit GeckoDriver based on your browser and you would need to set Firefox Binary.

Please check this article for complete setup details -

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Hi Anish, as mentioned above, this didn't worked. Also I've followed the instructions of the link you provided without success. My code:
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", ECC.FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH);

//    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
//    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

//    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    FirefoxOptions options  = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    
    localWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    break;

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of firefox is also problematic (FF 52, geckodriver 0.15, selenium 3.3.1). Try using firefox 50.1.0. It worked for me. Newest versions of Firefox are usually not supported by latest drivers.

Comment: Thanks, it was a problem with the maven dependencies as explained above. Thanks again